# Does "corroborate" in a scientific context imply confirmation rather "either confirmation or rejection" of findings from previous studies?

Tags: science, academia, non-native-english, scientific-language

I am a non-native English speaker writing a scientific paper.

I have question concerning the word **corroborate**. In my native language, one might say that a research project aim to corroborate findings from previous studies. Such a phrase (in my language) imply an equally and objectively balanced approach that may **or** may *not* confirm findings from previous studies.

However, I am concerned that **corroborate** as used in: `We aimed to (1) corroborate previous findings of x, y and z` does *not* imply that we may reject what have been found and reported in previous studies rather than seeking to confirm it.

In a scientific context investigating whether x may **or** may *not* correlate to a specific outcome, e.g. death, can **corroborate** correctly describe that we seek to investigate the correlation between x and death, which consequently results in either confirmation *or* rejection of previous findings?

I am concerned that **corroborate** used as in `We aimed to (1) corroborate previous findings of x, y and z` simply implies that we "aim to confirm what have been previously found" rather than meaning "confirming *or* rejecting previous findings".

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please add references, linked & attributed. I dont't see the problem as being the meaning of 'corroborate'. 'We aimed to corroborate ...' does not sound like a felicitous statement to me for an impartial investigation. 'We sought to corroborate ...' is more felicitous, recognising that such a quest, while aiming to add weight to a theory, recognises that results might not support the theory.

Comment: *To corroborate* means to confirm. But that's not a problem; the verbs *aim* and *seek* allow you to reject—you can aim and miss, seek and not find. If you can't corroborate, then reject.

Comment: Why not use something like 'test'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OED defines [corroborate](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/corroborate):

> to provide evidence or information that supports a statement, theory, etc.

By this definition, *corroborate* means that it supports the existing theory. It cannot mean that it rejects the existing theory.

Here is where it gets tricky. If the existing statement *rejected* an idea (say, that Corona beer transmits the coronavirus), then a new study could corroborate this rejection.

Corroboration also works for rejecting hypotheses. Say an existing study rejects a null hypothesis (which is a good thing in scientific circles). A new study that also rejects the same null hypothesis will be said to be corroborating both the existing study *and* the rejection.

Answer (score 0):

> - **corroborate** - verb,  to support with evidence or authority : make more certain. [**MW**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/corroborate). To strengthen or support with other evidence; make more certain. See Synonyms at confirm. [**TFD**](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/corroborate)

If you say that your study **corroborates previous studies**, it only means that you and previous workers **reached the same conclusion**, irrespective of the results.

These papers may be about the effectiveness of a drug, the results of a surgical procedure or the side-effects of an environmental agent, but it doesn't matter whether the results will be of any benefit.

You may also say that "the present study bears out the results found by so-and-so. "Corroborate" certainly sounds more scientific, though.

> - **bear out** - confirm, substantiate [**MW**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bear%20out).  Back up or confirm, as in The results bear out what he predicted. [**TFD**](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/bear+out)